# Run as admin cmd opens some common files location

Tags: command-line

After installing Adobe Flash CS4 application the run as administrator command prompt opens with some "C:\pro..\Com..\Adobe\Adobe Version cue.... " location. I want to open with default location only. if I enable UAC and than run as admin works fine. what could be the reason? I don't want any new pinned cmd. also the cmd start in is defined default only no changes in path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4900046/2683954) from StackOverflow would work:

> `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)"`